# Removing xsi:nil from serialized XML

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I am using XmlSerializer to serialize Objects to XML. In that I have used attribute `IsNullable =  true` for getting the element in the XML even if the value is null.

So When the values is `NULL`, its corresponding element is visible but with the extra attribute `xsi:nil="true"`.

Is there a way to remove that attribute in the serialized XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **ShouldSerialize{property_name}** method

For example if your property is SomeClassInstance

```
[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
public SomeClass SomeClassInstance { get; set; }
```

you can add a method to that class like this:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeSomeClassInstance()
{
    return (SomeClassInstance != null);
}
```

This way it will only appear in the output XML when it's not null.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx